# @XmlElementWrapper for unwrapped collections

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

The docs state the the *@XmlElementWrapper* annotation can be used for 'unwrapped' or 'wrapped' collections.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html

How do you configure it to produce an unwrapped collection?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you include `@XmlElementWrapper` it will add a grouping element:

```java
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(name="foo")
public List<Foo> getFoos() {
    return foos;
}
```

```xml
<root>
    <foos>
        <foo/>
        <foo/>
    </foos>
</foo>
```

and if you omit it, then it won't.

```java
@XmlElement(name="foo")
public List<Foo> getFoos() {
    return foos;
}
```

```xml
<root>
    <foo/>
    <foo/>
</foo>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxb-representing-null-and-empty.html

Comment: The documentation suggests that the @XmlElementWrapper supports two forms: "The annotation therefore supports two forms of serialization shown below."  It seems to imply that we can configure this annotation to produce an unwrapped collection.  Your example omits the annotation altogether.

Comment: @user106563 - The documentation may need to be cleaned up, can you share the link you are referring to?  If you add the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation there will always be a grouping element (as long as the value is not null).

Comment: Check out the first paragraph of the following link:  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html

Comment: @user106563 - I agree that javadoc is confusing.  In reality `@XmlElementWrapper` works as I described.  FWIW I'm a member of the JAXB (JSR-222) expert group and you can find my name in the spec:  http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222

Comment: This solution has one drawback. When changing to JSON, the name of the list becomes the name given in @XmlElement (aka, the singular). Any idea on how to circumnavigate this?