# XSD mapping to Java POJOs

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

Let's say I have an XML source from a web service, that I have no control over, with the following structure:

```
<wrapper>
    <baz>content</baz>
    <foo>
        <bar>content</bar>
        <bar>content</bar>
    </foo>
</wrapper>
```

The corresponding XSD is the following:

```
<xsd:complexType name="wrapper">
    <xsd:element name="baz" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="foo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="bar" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:complexType>
```

From that XSD JAXB generates the following Java class:

```
@XmlType(name = "wrapper")
public class Wrapper {

    @XmlElement
    protected String baz;

    @XmlElement
    protected Foo foo;

    @XmlType(name = "foo")
    public static class Foo {

        @XmlElement
        protected List<String> bar;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to refactor/annotate the POJO so that instead of *Wrapper* having a *Foo* object it contains the List of *Bar* objects?

If it helps I'm currently consuming the web service with Spring-WS and using the default Jaxb2Marshaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add **@XmlElementWrapper** annotation. Check this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202583/xmlelementwrapper-for-unwrapped-collections) for more information.

```
@XmlRootElement    
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Wrapper {
    @XmlElement
    protected String baz;

    @XmlElement(name = "bar")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "foo")
    protected List<String> bars;

    public String getBaz() {
        return baz;
    }

    public void setBaz(String baz) {
        this.baz = baz;
    }

    public List<String> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

    public void setBars(List<String> bars) {
        this.bars = bars;
    }
}
```