# Java:Jax reading and writing xml, classes confusion

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Hello i am new to xml reading/writing and am not sure if i doing reading correctly.I am using Java core with jaxb-api version 2.1.What i want to do is basically create product objects and write them to a different file based on this xml.the problem is that i am not sure how to mark the fields
do i need to create only an Order class and add the products as wrappers for the fields that are inside or do i need to create a product class aswell?
it is confusing for me since product is inside order but it acts like a wrapper for the other tags inside.
I am finding several tutorials online but none of them handle a List of objects, most of the examples contain simple String fields or arrays of Strings.So i am not sure how to handle this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much

```
<orders>
    <order created='2012-07-12T15:29:33.000' ID='2343'>
        <product>
            <description>Sony 54.6" (Diag) Xbr Hx929 Internet Tv</description>
            <gtin>00027242816657</gtin>
            <price currency="USD">2999.99</price>
            <supplier>Sony</supplier>
        </product>
        <product>
            <description>Apple iPad 2 with Wi-Fi 16GB - iOS 5 - Black</description>
            <gtin>00885909464517</gtin>
            <price currency="USD">399.0</price>
            <supplier>Apple</supplier>
        </product>
        <product>
            <description>Sony NWZ-E464 8GB E Series Walkman Video MP3 Player Blue</description>
            <gtin>00027242831438</gtin>
            <price currency="USD">91.99</price>
            <supplier>Sony</supplier>
        </product>
    </order>
    <order created='2012-07-13T16:02:22.000' ID='2344'>
        <product>
            <description>Apple MacBook Air A 11.6" Mac OS X v10.7 Lion MacBook</description>
            <gtin>00885909464043</gtin>
            <price currency="USD">1149.0</price>
            <supplier>Apple</supplier>
        </product>
        <product>
            <description>Panasonic TC-L47E50 47" Smart TV Viera E50 Series LED HDTV</description>
            <gtin>00885170076471</gtin>
            <price currency="USD">999.99</price>
            <supplier>Panasonic</supplier>
        </product>
    </order>
</orders>
```

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Order {
    private LocalDateTime created;
    private List<Product> products;


    public LocalDateTime getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setCreated(LocalDateTime created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="product")
    @XmlElement
    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need an `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation, but you need to give a `name` parameter to the `@XmlElement` annotation. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16202799/11748454) to see how it works.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thanks, ok so no wrapper, but then how do i write the class that contains the products?Could you explain this to me please with some code example in a sepparate answer?I will give you rep for it.

Comment: There are a lot of good tutorials on JAXB on the web. Check, e.g. [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xml#useful-resources-3). [Most](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/12/jaxb-tutorial-xml-binding.html) [of](https://java2blog.com/jaxb-tutorial/) [them](https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/) have examples similar to yours. They provide a better answer.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.
(In order not to spoil your learning experience, I will only give some instructions, but no complete code.)

- To represent   the XML root element `<orders>...</orders>`
  you need another class (let's call it `Orders`).

  - Annotate it with `@XmlRootElement`.
  - The `<orders>` element  contains several `<order>` elements.
    Therefore you need to add a member `List<Order> orders`.
    Annotate it with `@XmlElement(name="order")`.
- In your `Order` class:

  - You don't need the `@XmlRootElement` annotation here,
    because `<order>` is not the root element.
  - Annotate the `products` with only `@XmlElement(name="product")`
    (as already written by @PiotrP.Karwasz in his comment).
  - Annotate the `created` member with `@XmlAttribute` instead of `@XmlElement`.
    This is because you have an XML attribute `created="something"`,
    not an XML element `<created>something</created>`.
  - JAXB will probably complain that it doesn't support `LocalDateTime`.
    So you may need to change this to `Date`.

Comment: Thank you very much !